# Would an ideal, p-n based LED, ever stop producing light if it had a finite amount of doping?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, light-emitting-diodes

I'm trying to understand how long would an LED last if there were no manufacturing/wear and tear imperfections in the product, just by exhaustion of the material that allows the transduction of electricity to light. In this case I understand that this material is the doping in the junction, and once all the holes of the P-material have been recombined with the free electrons of the N-material, no more reaction should occur in the LED to the pass of current through it.

Is this correct? In case it is, how long would it take to exhaust the doping in an average commercial LED?

Comment: You need to inject current into the junction. That is what provides the charges to recombine and emit light.

Comment: Over a very long period of time the p and n dopants will diffuse and the junction degrades until the LED stops performing. This depends on temperature. The hotter the LED operates the faster this process occurs. Typically 50 years.

Comment: Besides diffusion, does every recombination of hole with current electron "use up" one of the holes, or are can they be regenerated by some means applying external voltage, etc. (without doping the material again)